# Scaffolding tool with Blazor wasm

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages

Is it possible to have CRUD files and capability with a Blazor WebAssembly app? The same way you can with an Razor Pages by using the scaffolding tool. I'm trying to build a Blazor WebAssmebly app that has CRUD capabilities with a local DB.

Comment: I have not seen any official ones, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm going to try and do it the way you would with Razor pages(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-the-web-app-project). I'm hoping that because the blazor apps are written using razor markup it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Blazor Scaffolding support is provided only for Blazor ServerSide application and Blazor Hosted application.  [Checkout the Syncfusion documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/extension/blazor-extension/visual-studio/scaffolding)

In your case you should create another project with Blazor Server instead of Blazor WebAssembly to get those Scafold options for CRUD generation files on Visual Studio